# I want to create a cron job with nodejs, but How can I check that the previous job is finished or not?

Tags: node.js

I want to create a cron job with nodejs. But How can I check the previous is finished or not? I just want one job is running at the same time.

Comment: store somewhere status of job (redis for example or another db)

Answer (score 0):

There is a great library for cron jobs in Node.JS: [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

The "nature" of cron jobs is that they are be executed periodically. If you want a job to start only if the previous job has finished, you can use a flag (set it to true at the start of the job, set it to false at the end of the job - then new jobs can check if the flag is true).

BUT, maybe you should use a job queue - once a job has finished, the next job will start executing. That depends on your scenario, so please provide more information.

A popular library that has queues: [collections](https://www.npmjs.com/package/collections).

Comment: I tried to use it. I found that the next task will not start if the previous is not finished. here is my code https://github.com/xiaoshao/nodejs_cron_example/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

You could combine [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) and [async's queues](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#queue), for example:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var async = require('async');
var NUMBER_CONCURRENT_JOBS = 1;

var q = async.queue(function(task, callback) {
    task(callback);
}, NUMBER_CONCURRENT_JOBS);

var job = function(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('JOB EXECUTED');
        callback();
    }, 5000);
}

new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
    console.log('JOB REQUIRED');
    q.push(job);
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```